# In the chef resource document, why do they have parenthesis around the name in the template resource in the execute examples?

Tags: chef

I'm looking at the http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#execute and under "Execute" in "Execute a command using a template", they call template with parenthesis around the argument. Just a handful of statements earlier, they call execute sans parenthesis. For the rest of the document, template is called without parenthesis. Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

```
execute "forward_ipv4" do
  command "echo > /proc/.../ipv4/ip_forward"
  action :nothing
end

template( "/etc/file_name.conf" ) do
  source "routing/file_name.conf.erb"
  notifies :run, 'execute[forward_ipv4]', :delayed
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen that syntax/style before until you pointed it out.  It's completely unnecessary and confusing to use parentheses in that situation.  Just specifying the template and the filename is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'll go bring this inconsistency in documentation up in their [issues tracker](https://github.com/opscode/chef-docs) then. Thanks!

Comment: And done: https://github.com/opscode/chef-docs/issues/26

Answer (score 1):

Chef recipes are written in Ruby, and the DSL uses `#method_missing` for defining resources in recipes.

Thus, each resource is a method, which takes a single argument (a string, the name), and a block (the parameters).

Parentheses are optional around the arguments in Ruby, and there is much written about whether to use them [on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+parenthesis+or+not). While it doesn't matter whether you use them in Chef resources, most often they are omitted.

However, if you wish to write a resource on a single line, you'll need parentheses:

```
execute "echo Hello" { action :nothing }

SyntaxError: (irb#1):1: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end
execute "echo Hello" { action :nothing }
                      ^

execute("echo Hello") { action :nothing }

 => <execute[echo Hello] @name: "echo Hello" @noop: nil @before: nil
 @params: {} @provider: nil @allowed_actions: [:nothing, :run]
 @action: [:nothing] @updated: false @updated_by_last_action: false
 @supports: {} @ignore_failure: false @retries: 0 @retry_delay: 2
 @source_line: "(irb#1):2:in `irb_binding'" @elapsed_time: 0
 @resource_name: :execute @command: "echo Hello" @backup: 5 @creates:
 nil @cwd: nil @environment: nil @group: nil @path: nil @returns: 0
 @timeout: nil @user: nil @umask: nil @cookbook_name: nil
 @recipe_name: nil>
```

(action nothing here is just to show an example)